# VLC output to DirectShow

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, directshow

I have a playlist of video files in various formats (which VLC will happily play while others choke on some of them).

I have another program which will only accept as input a DirectShow Source device (eg. webcam).

I would like some way to create a virtual Source device that lets me play the playlist in VLC and have it capture video and audio and output them from the Source device, so that I can feed it into the other program.  (Synchronised, of course, and realtime with no intermediate files.)

Ideally the audio should go through "pure" (only the audio from the playlist, not picking up anything else played by other applications) but this is not essential.

I don't mind writing some code myself if I need to, but this seems like something that ought to exist already somewhere?

I'm open to using something other than VLC, provided it's free and can cope with the video formats.

Comment: A twin question on StackOverflow covering solution through developement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174791/vlc-output-to-directshow-source-filter